# About using a neural network to train another neural network (on the same problem)

Tags: reinforcement-learning

While experimenting with OpenAI gym to play a bit with reinforcement learning, I ended with using an approach that I can't exactly say what type of paradigm of training is, and I'd like to get your help.
I tried with the simplest game OpenAI gym offers, i.e CartPole game - I think it's more or less the "hello world"  in RL problems.I approached the problem this way: I used an agent to play *n* games, each time memorizing only games with a total score more than a given threeshold, and using collect data from "selected" games to train a second agent. 
Then, this second agent  has been used to play other *n* games to train another agent instance, and so on, until the last agent was able to beat the game (reaching 500 points). At the very first step, the agent acts completely randomly; next instances use a neural network to choose which action perform.
At each session, I increment the threeshold only when the agent played no more than an *x* percentage of games under the assigned threeshold.
At the very end, this approached worked but the fact it worked - and I was able to repeat the experiment from scratch - doesn't imply that's a good approach.
Moreover, I don't know how a similar approach could be named. I think about Adversarial neural networks, but I'm pretty sure it's not the same thing..
Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: that's a pretty creative approach, i haven't heard about it anywhere else. would probably call it something like iterated imitation learning

Comment: compare to iterated amplification used in alphazero, where random search and threshold is replaced with mcts

Comment: Thanks shimao for your reply. It's worth to say that this approach it's also very slow. I will give a look at iterated amplification.